# How to retrieve the lost password for my Yahoo email account?

Tags: yahoo-mail, account-recovery, yahoo-account

Is there a way to retrieve an email account password?

I've tried calling the company myself but they need the answers to the security question... of which were created 7 years ago along with the account and I can't remember for the life of me.

How to handle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If [this help page](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/edit/id_password/edit-20.html) is accurate (and I don't see why it shouldn't), it's only possible with:

- an alternate email address (previously associated with your account);
- a mobile phone number (also previously associated with your account);
- or the answers to the secret questions.

Other than that, I think you're pretty much out of luck.