# Forgot my Yahoo! mail password

Tags: yahoo-mail, password-recovery, yahoo-account

I forgot my Yahoo! mail password and I am very interested in accessing and maintaining my Yahoo! mail account because it contains a lot of data since 2003. What can I do to recover or change my Yahoo! mail password?

Comment: See here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9373/how-to-retrieve-the-lost-password-for-my-email-account?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

Go to Yahoo [password recovery](https://edit.yahoo.com/forgotroot/) page and follow the instructions.

In your case select the first option and click on Next.
Enter your Yahoo ID, you will redirect to **How would you like to recover access to your account?** page with options to recover like:

- Send an email to *alternatemailid*
- Send a text message to : *phone number*
- Answer the security questions

Select anyone option and click next. Follow the instructions and you will be able to recover your account. See [Reset your forgotten password](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN2047.html) for more information.

If you are not able to recover by above method, go to below page to contact customer care, fill the form and wait for the answer.

[Online Help](https://io.help.yahoo.com/contact/index?locale=en_US&y=PROD_ACCT&page=contact&actp=lorax):

- Select password and sign in.
- Forgot my password.
- Click on the envelope (Email).
- Fill the form.
- Click on *Create Request*.

Comment: @karel : When you click on _Forgot my password_ you will be ask to enter your Yahoo id. Once you submit the Yahoo id, you will see two options, 1. _Go to Password Helper_ (Which is right side), 2. _We're here to help!_ with a envelop symbol (Email) (Which is down side). Click on that envelop.