# How to recover Yahoo! mail account

Tags: yahoo-mail, yahoo-account

I still remember my Yahoo! ID and password but the problem is when I login, I'm asked to provide the security question which I already forgot the answer. I don't have any other recovery ways like "alternate email" or "phone number".

I tried also the answers from this [Forgot my Yahoo! mail password](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/80788/forgot-my-yahoo-mail-password) but seems to be not applicable to me or not working.

Is there any email we can send for support? Since hotline numbers are for UK & Canada only I think.

Comment: When you tried to change the password, what the error you are facing? _seems to be not applicable to me or not working_ is not a problem. Explain what is not working.

Comment: Its not applicable since the solutions offered is by having an alternate email address or a mobile number which both I havent provided. The only option yahoo is giving me is the "secret question" option which is the problem I stated

Answer (score 2):

You can try these links for contacting Yahoo! Support Team for help,

[Yahoo! Help Central](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/helpcentral)

[Contact Yahoo! Customer Support](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN26180.html?impressions=true)

[Select the product you need help with](https://io.help.yahoo.com/contact/index?page=home&locale=en_US)

[Help for Yahoo! Mail](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/mail-for-desktop)

---

Go to [THIS LINK](https://io.help.yahoo.com/contact/index?page=contact&locale=en_US&y=PROD_MAIL_ML#) and,

1. Select Errors under Topics.
2. Select "My issue does not appear on the list" under "Sub-Topics".
3. Under "Recommended Options" enter your YAHOO ID and follow the instructions.

[HERE](http://www.wikihow.com/Contact-Yahoo) you will find other contact profile of YAHOO like Twitter and Facebook accounts...

Comment: Im looking for an email address like email us at `support@yahoo.com` which I can write an email about my problem. All the links just lead to the Community Forum.

Comment: I've added another method for contacting Yahoo!

Comment: Ive tried it I hope this works. thank you for the effort.